# Column Formatting or SPFX field customizer for button if no value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am working on a modern list and have the task of placing a "claim" button in a field. The button will appear when the field has not been assigned yet and clicking the button will assign a value to the field. I have attempted column formatting but I cannot get both the action button and the assigned value to the column to appear at the same time.

My trail and error has caused me to lean towards building a field customizer extension but I felt I would see if anyone has any input or ideas.

I have used the generic flow example as my starting point: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-column-formatting/tree/master/samples/generic-start-flow

Thanks for any thoughts